# Runnables in Spring's Task Scheduler

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the below snippet in Spring to schedule job executions. A job is found by querying the database. Once a new job is found (which has not yet been scheduled), it is scheduled programmatically.

My question is, is this the way to create Runnables for task execution? Is it accessing `taskScheduler` in the right way or should it access it by fetching an instance from application context?

```
@Service
public class TimeOfDayScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private JobExecutor jobExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.interval}")
    @PostConstruct
    public void findNewJobs() {
        // Checks the database if any new jobs should be scheduled
        // ...
        // If found:

        scheduleJob(somejob);

        // ...
    }

    public void scheduleJob(final Job job) {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {                    
                    jobExecutor.execute(job);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Scheduler error", e);
                }
            }
        };

        taskScheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger(job.getCronPattern())
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you prevent duplicate scheduling?

Comment: The class is not complete, actually there is a map holding submitted jobs. But my question was more geared towards calling `jobExecutor.execute()`, can it be called this way within the Runnable?

Comment: Then there is nothing wrong with your implementation. This is how the scheduler should be used.

Comment: I would simply remove the `@PostConstruct`. The `findNewJobs` method will be run automatically because of `@Scheduled`.